# Regex to remove decimals correctly

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a regex that leaves just numbers from the below numbers. The output should be:

```
1000
1000
10000
10000
```

The problem is that the regex for removing decimals also removes all the zeros from the first number, leaving a single number.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/28dL2fvp/11/

Script:

```
$("em.price.product-card-price").each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.html($this.html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "").replace(/(\.\d+)+/,''), 10);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    €1.000&nbsp;
 </em>
</div>

<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    1&nbsp;000&nbsp;
 </em>
</div>

<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    10,000.00SEK&nbsp;
 </em>
</div>

<div class="left">
 <em class="price product-card-price">
    SEK10,000.00&nbsp; 
 </em>
</div>
```

Comment: `1.000 == 1`, it's doing the right thing... what's wrong with it??

Comment: Its doing just that, thats the problem. It should be 1000. I initially just wanted to remove the .00 from the 10000.00 number, but not sure how to write it so it doesn't affect the first number.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/28dL2fvp/13/

Comment: @JerrySvensson You convert `1.000` to `1000` but `10,000.00` to `10000`?!

Comment: Yes I know it looks wierd - but it is because the numbers is different currencies, and not present at the same time. i just need the script to cover both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.` from string if it follows more than two decimal digits.

```
$("em.price.product-card-price").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/[^0-9.]|\.(?=\d{3,})/g, "").replace(/(\.\d+)+/,''), 10);
});
```

```js
$("em.price.product-card-price").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.html($this.html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/[^0-9.]|\.(?=\d{3,})/g, "").replace(/(\.\d+)+/, ''), 10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
  <em class="price product-card-price">
        €1.000&nbsp;
    </em>

</div>
<div class="left">
  <em class="price product-card-price">
        1&nbsp;000&nbsp;
    </em>
</div>

<div class="left">
  <em class="price product-card-price">
        10,000.00SEK&nbsp;
    </em>

</div>

<div class="left">
  <em class="price product-card-price">
        SEK10,000.00&nbsp; 
    </em>
</div>
```

---

[Regex explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/uP3rW6/1)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Will accept as answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @JerrySvensson :  glad to help :)